# getting body empty while using fetch but not in case of axios

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, fetch

```
      onsubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const formdata = new FormData();
        const body ={
          'file':'file',
          'hello': 'hello'
        }


        let options = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: url,
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
          },
          data: body
        }

        let response = await axios(options);

        let res  = await fetch(url,{
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
          },
          data: JSON.stringify(body)
        })
      }
```

when i using fetch method to make post request at backend side when i do console.log(req.body) {} empty is printed but while using axios body is getting printed why this is happening. Please figure out and reply

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.